# How can I revert the whole project to a time point in Android Studio with GitHub?

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I'm a beginner of GitHub, as the following Image, I commit a project many times to GitHub in Android Studio.

Now I hope to revert the project to the time point "My Good", how can I operate? I can't any command button in Android Studio.

**Image**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I checkout an old git commit in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36517118/how-do-i-checkout-an-old-git-commit-in-android-studio)

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is OK, but I get the error "Detached HEAD" when I try to Push the project to GitHub after I  have finished the Checkout Revision . You can see it at https://www.dropbox.com/s/g1nxz11x113pg5a/detached.png?dl=0 .why?

Comment: Sorry.  My original suggestion just helped you get the "old" version.  Now you *also* need to revert your *current* master to that old version. That's not "difficult": you need to do a [Git rebase](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase).  These links might help: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-git-in-android-studio--cms-30514, [How Can I Reconcile Detached Head With master/origin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/) or  https://gyulajuhasz.com/blog/rebasing-in-android-studio/